# Cannot make my SSH readable only for me

Tags: ssh, openshift

I want to be able to push changes to OpenShift but I cant make a normal SSH key. Always when I run rhc setup it says:

`Your private SSH key file should be set as readable only to yourself.  Please
run 'chmod 600 C:\Users\Slavi\.ssh\id_rsa'`

I tried many things , Cygwin, deleting and making new keys, trying to change the permissions manualy, nothing helps, the same error over and over again. So after hours of trying I give up.

I know this problem is been asked a lot but I just couldnt find solution for my case. Is there any workaround I can try?

Comment: Did you try running the command suggested in the error message? It's not clear from your question if you did that or not.  Also, there appear to be a lot of Google results for this particular situation; can you provide more details about what you've tried?

Comment: Hello, yes I tried running the command from the cmd. But I'm with windows => it's now working, that's why I mentioned Cygwin, I installed it and runned the command from there but it looks like it didn't work. Yes a lot of similar problems are shown when you google that and just I didn't find any solution. I think a possible solution would be making the file only readable only for me manualy but I failed trying that.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a nap I started re-reading all the posts and questions about the problem and I found what I have missed.

> you might've had accidentaly configure Git with ssh, thus Git will have it's own .ssh folder in sth like C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/.ssh, copy your keys there

Eventhough I still can't login properly with rhc setup (same error) now my git works fine after I copied the keys in the ../Git/.ssh folder. For me that's enough.